# Need to add and delete items from a Shopping Cart using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopping-cart

I'm having trouble with my homework assignment. I need to create a Shopping Cart using Javascript, HTML5 and JQuery, and it must collect all the items from the shop inside an Array. I think I pretty much solved it, but I cannot figure out how to add multiple of the same item to the cart without it creating 2 different objects on the cart list.

Also, if possible, I would like to be able to change the amount of certain items directly from the cart, with the option of upgrading or downgrading the quantity.

This is what I've got going on at the moment:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            // Variables
            var baseDeDatos = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    nombre: 'Jean Mom',
                    precio: 1399
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    nombre: 'Pant Ren',
                    precio: 990
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    nombre: 'Buzo Largo Hailey',
                    precio: 948
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    nombre: 'Cycle Short',
                    precio: 550
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    nombre: 'Top Cellie',
                    precio: 590
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    nombre: 'Jacket Denim Ray',
                    precio: 2890
                },
                {
                    id: 7,
                    nombre: 'Cinto Vice',
                    precio: 499
                },
                {
                    id: 8,
                    nombre: 'Top Caro',
                    precio: 499
                },
                {
                    id: 9,
                    nombre: 'Bra Top Regan',
                    precio: 590
                },
                {
                    id: 10,
                    nombre: 'Sweater Polly',
                    precio: 1399
                },
                {
                    id: 11,
                    nombre: 'Camisa June',
                    precio: 799
                },
                {
                    id: 12,
                    nombre: 'Pant Amy',
                    precio: 1299
                },
                {
                    id: 13,
                    nombre: 'Top Tai',
                    precio: 648
                },
                {
                    id: 14,
                    nombre: 'Tapado Judy',
                    precio: 3290
                },
                {
                    id: 15,
                    nombre: 'Mini Corderoy Lou',
                    precio: 1090
                }

            ]
            
            var $items = document.querySelector('#items');
            var carrito = [];
            var total = 0;
            var $carrito = document.querySelector('#carrito');
            var $total = document.querySelector('#total');
            // Funciones
            function renderItems () {
                for (var info of baseDeDatos) {
                    // Estructura
                    var miNodo = document.createElement('div');
                    miNodo.classList.add('card', 'col-sm-4');
                    // Body
                    var miNodoCardBody = document.createElement('div');
                    miNodoCardBody.classList.add('card-body');
                    // Titulo
                    var miNodoTitle = document.createElement('h5');
                    miNodoTitle.classList.add('card-title');
                    miNodoTitle.textContent = info['nombre'];
                    // Precio
                    var miNodoPrecio = document.createElement('p');
                    miNodoPrecio.classList.add('card-text');
                    miNodoPrecio.textContent = '$' +info['precio'];
                    // Boton 
                    var miNodoBoton = document.createElement('button');
                    miNodoBoton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
                    miNodoBoton.textContent = '+';
                    miNodoBoton.setAttribute('marcador', info['id']);
                    miNodoBoton.addEventListener('click', anyadirCarrito);
                    // Insertamos
                    miNodoCardBody.appendChild(miNodoTitle);
                    miNodoCardBody.appendChild(miNodoPrecio);
                    miNodoCardBody.appendChild(miNodoBoton);
                    miNodo.appendChild(miNodoCardBody);
                    $items.appendChild(miNodo);
                }
            }
            function anyadirCarrito () {
                // Anyadimos el Nodo a nuestro carrito
                carrito.push(this.getAttribute('marcador'))
                // Calculo el total
                calcularTotal();
                // Renderizamos el carrito 
                renderizarCarrito();

            }

            function renderizarCarrito () {
                // Vaciamos todo el html
                $carrito.textContent = '';
                // Generamos los Nodos a partir de carrito
                carrito.forEach(function (item, indice) {
                    // Obtenemos el item que necesitamos de la variable base de datos
                    var miItem = baseDeDatos.filter(function(itemBaseDatos) {
                        return itemBaseDatos['id'] == item;
                    });
                    // Creamos el nodo del item del carrito
                    var miNodo = document.createElement('li');
                    miNodo.classList.add('list-group-item', 'text-right');
                    miNodo.textContent = `${miItem[0]['nombre']} - $${miItem[0]['precio']}`;
                    // Boton de borrar
                    var miBoton = document.createElement('button');
                    miBoton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger', 'mx-5');
                    miBoton.textContent = 'X';
                    miBoton.setAttribute('posicion', indice);
                    miBoton.addEventListener('click', borrarItemCarrito);
                    // Mezclamos nodos
                    miNodo.appendChild(miBoton);
                    $carrito.appendChild(miNodo);
                })
            }

            function borrarItemCarrito () {
                // Obtenemos la posicion que hay en el boton pulsado
                var posicion = this.getAttribute('posicion');
                // Borramos la posicion que nos interesa
                carrito.splice(posicion, 1);
                // volvemos a renderizar
                renderizarCarrito();
                // Calculamos de nuevo el precio
                calcularTotal();
            }

            function calcularTotal () {
                // Limpiamos precio anterior
                total = 0;
                // Recorremos el array del carrito
                for (var item of carrito) {
                    // De cada elemento obtenemos su precio
                    var miItem = baseDeDatos.filter(function(itemBaseDatos) {
                        return itemBaseDatos['id'] == item;
                    });
                    total = total + miItem[0]['precio'];
                }
                // Formateamos el total para que solo tenga dos decimales
                var totalDosDecimales = total.toFixed(2);
                // Renderizamos el precio en el HTML
                $total.textContent = totalDosDecimales;
            }
            // Eventos

            // Inicio
            renderItems();
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Elementos generados a partir del JSON -->
            <main id="items" class="col-sm-8 row"></main>
            <!-- Carrito -->
            <aside class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Carrito</h2>
                <!-- Elementos del carrito -->
                <ul id="carrito" class="list-group"></ul>
                <hr>
                <!-- Precio total -->
                <p class="text-right">Total: <span id="total"></span>&dollar;</p>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Oh, and I don't really know how to implement jQuery into what I already have in my code, so any suggestions would be highly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the input quantity, here the example:

```
function renderizarCarrito() {
  // Vaciamos todo el html
  $carrito.textContent = '';
  // Generamos los Nodos a partir de carrito
  arrayCart.forEach(function (item, indice) {
    // Obtenemos el item que necesitamos de la variable base de datos
    // Creamos el nodo del item del carrito
    var miNodo = document.createElement('li');
    var inputCantidad = document.createElement('input');
    inputCantidad.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    inputCantidad.setAttribute('min', '0');
    inputCantidad.setAttribute('max', '10');
    inputCantidad.setAttribute('value', arrayCart[indice]['cantidad']);
    inputCantidad.classList.add('input-list');
    miNodo.classList.add('list-group-item', 'text-right');
    miNodo.textContent = `${arrayCart[indice]['nombre']} - $${arrayCart[indice]['precio']} - `;
    // Boton de borrar
    var miBoton = document.createElement('button');
    miBoton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger', 'mx-5');
    miBoton.textContent = 'X';
    miBoton.setAttribute('posicion', indice);
    miBoton.addEventListener('click', borrarItemCarrito);
    // Mezclamos nodos

    miNodo.appendChild(inputCantidad);
    miNodo.appendChild(miBoton);
    $carrito.appendChild(miNodo);
  })
}
```

And you get:

[image]

I can help you only here, regards.

Answer (score 0):

you have unique id right?so,add item before judge item.id is or not already in cart

Answer (score 0):

A few quick jQuery pointers:

1. You are missing the jQuery and bootstrap javascript files. You only included the bootstrap CSS file - so you don't actually *have* jQuery in your page, or most of Bootstrap (*some* of the bootstrap will work, which will be confusing). To solve: In your head, replace this one line:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

with these four lines:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2. jQuery Tip: Replace this: `window.onload = function () {` with

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
```

3. jQuery Tip: Replace this: `document.querySelector` with this: `$`

```
    Example FROM:  document.querySelector('#items');
              TO:  $('#items');
```

4. Use jQuery `.on()` - When the page is first created ("rendered"), javascript is run immediately. If some js code runs that binds an event listener to an element ***before*** the element is created, that event listener will not be attached! We use `document.ready` to solve that. `document.ready` says, "delay running all the code inside this function (that is, inside the document.ready function code block) ***until*** all the HTML elements have been rendered (created and placed on the page)".

But a *similar problem* is how to attach an event listener to an element that gets added to the page LATER ON -- and jQuery `.on()` is how you do that. Basically, you add a jQuery `.on()` function block right off the start, and ***later on, when one of those elements is added to the DOM, the event handler will be attached on-the-fly.*** This is reason #47 why we love jQuery.

5. As a convention/tradition (not a *rule*), we generally prefix *variables-that-are-jQuery-objects* with the `$`. In variable names, the `$` doesn't *do* anything, it just reminds us that this is a jQuery object and we can use jQuery methods/properties on it directly.

The purpose of StackOverflow is to *assist*, not to *write-it-for-you*. So, in that spirit, I have turned your js into jQuery. If you look at it carefully, you will see that it is exactly what you wrote - just switched over to jQuery.

It is now *your* job to make the code work. Not everything that I did is finished/working. Every line still needs to be reviewed/tested/tweaked. But at least now you can get started.

Notice that I added the word `debugger;` to your javascript. *IF* you are testing in Google Chrome -- and *IF* you have DevTools open (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) -- *THEN* the `debugger` statement will allow you to step-through your code line-by-line. This is the single best tool you will ever find to figure out how to get this working.

#### NON-WORKING Stack Snippet:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Variables
        debugger;
        var baseDeDatos = [
            {
                id: 1,
                nombre: 'Jean Mom',
                precio: 1399
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                nombre: 'Pant Ren',
                precio: 990
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                nombre: 'Buzo Largo Hailey',
                precio: 948
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                nombre: 'Cycle Short',
                precio: 550
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                nombre: 'Top Cellie',
                precio: 590
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                nombre: 'Jacket Denim Ray',
                precio: 2890
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                nombre: 'Cinto Vice',
                precio: 499
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                nombre: 'Top Caro',
                precio: 499
            },
            {
                id: 9,
                nombre: 'Bra Top Regan',
                precio: 590
            },
            {
                id: 10,
                nombre: 'Sweater Polly',
                precio: 1399
            },
            {
                id: 11,
                nombre: 'Camisa June',
                precio: 799
            },
            {
                id: 12,
                nombre: 'Pant Amy',
                precio: 1299
            },
            {
                id: 13,
                nombre: 'Top Tai',
                precio: 648
            },
            {
                id: 14,
                nombre: 'Tapado Judy',
                precio: 3290
            },
            {
                id: 15,
                nombre: 'Mini Corderoy Lou',
                precio: 1090
            }

        ]
        
        var $items = $('#items');
        var carrito = [];
        var total = 0;
        var $carrito = $('#carrito');
        var $total = $('#total');
        
        //Use jQuery .on() method to attach an event handler to ALL FUTURE such elements
        $(document).on('click', 'button.item-button', function(){
            debugger;
            $this = $(this);
            anyadirCarrito($this)
        });
        $(document).on('click', 'carr-button', function(){
            $this = $(this);
            borrarItemCarrito($this);
        });


        // Funciones
        function renderItems () {
            for (var info of baseDeDatos) {
                // Estructura
                var $miNodo = $('div');
                miNodo.addClass('card', 'col-sm-4');
                // Body
                var $miNodoCardBody = $('div');
                miNodoCardBody.addClass('card-body');
                // Titulo
                var $miNodoTitle = $('h5');
                $miNodoTitle.addClass('card-title');
                $miNodoTitle.text(info['nombre']);
                // Precio
                var $miNodoPrecio = $('p');
                $miNodoPrecio.addClass('card-text');
                $miNodoPrecio.text('$' + info['precio']);
                // Boton 
                var $miNodoBoton = $('button');
                $miNodoBoton.addClass('btn', 'btn-primary', 'item-button');
                $miNodoBoton.text('+');
                $miNodoBoton.attr('marcador', info['id']));
                // Insertamos
                $miNodoCardBody.append($miNodoTitle);
                $miNodoCardBody.append($miNodoPrecio);
                $miNodoCardBody.append($miNodoBoton);
                $miNodo.append($miNodoCardBody);
                $items.append($miNodo);
            }
        }
        function anyadirCarrito ($this) {
            // Anyadimos el Nodo a nuestro carrito
            carrito.push($this.getAttribute('marcador'))
            // Calculo el total
            calcularTotal($this);
            // Renderizamos el carrito 
            renderizarCarrito($this);

        }

        function renderizarCarrito ($this, carrito) {
            //What is "carrito" and where is it created? It needs to be added to the fn call
            // Vaciamos todo el html
            carrito.text(); //clear it
            // Generamos los Nodos a partir de carrito
            carrito.forEach(function (item, indice) {
                // Obtenemos el item que necesitamos de la variable base de datos
                var miItem = baseDeDatos.filter(function(itemBaseDatos) {
                    return itemBaseDatos['id'] == item;
                });
                // Creamos el nodo del item del carrito
                var $miNodo = $('li');
                $miNodo.addClass('list-group-item', 'text-right');
                let summat = `${miItem[0]['nombre']} - $${miItem[0]['precio']}`;
                $miNodo.text(summat);
                // Boton de borrar
                var $miBoton = $('button');
                $miBoton.addClass('btn', 'btn-danger', 'mx-5', 'carr-button');
                $miBoton.text('X');
                $miBoton.attr('posicion', indice);
                // Mezclamos nodos
                $miNodo.append($miBoton);
                carrito.append($miNodo);
            });
        }

        function borrarItemCarrito ($this, carrito) {
            // Obtenemos la posicion que hay en el boton pulsado
            var posicion = $this.attr('posicion');
            // Borramos la posicion que nos interesa
            carrito.splice(posicion, 1);
            // volvemos a renderizar
            renderizarCarrito($this, carrito);
            // Calculamos de nuevo el precio
            calcularTotal($this);
        }

        function calcularTotal () {
            // Limpiamos precio anterior
            total = 0;
            // Recorremos el array del carrito
            for (var item of carrito) {
                // De cada elemento obtenemos su precio
                var miItem = baseDeDatos.filter(function(itemBaseDatos) {
                    return itemBaseDatos['id'] == item;
                });
                total = total + miItem[0]['precio'];
            }
            // Formateamos el total para que solo tenga dos decimales
            var totalDosDecimales = total.toFixed(2);
            // Renderizamos el precio en el HTML
            // ERROR var total is not an html element, is it? You can only use `.text()` (and .textContent) on an ELEMENT
            $total.textContent = totalDosDecimales;
        }
        // Eventos

        // Inicio
        renderItems();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Elementos generados a partir del JSON -->
            <main id="items" class="col-sm-8 row"></main>
            <!-- Carrito -->
            <aside class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Carrito</h2>
                <!-- Elementos del carrito -->
                <ul id="carrito" class="list-group"></ul>
                <hr>
                <!-- Precio total -->
                <p class="text-right">Total: <span id="total"></span>&dollar;</p>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```