# how to write a function to remove an item from the shopping cart while clicking on the delete

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

how to write a function to remove item from cart . I added item to cart by storing it in local Storage now i want to remove item from cart and remove the item from local storage how to do that

```js
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

let products = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Sandwich', price: 99, active: 'Yes', dateOfLaunch: '15/03/2017', category: 'Main Course', freeDelivery: 'Yes',inCart:0 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Burger', price: 129, active: 'Yes', dateOfLaunch: '23/12/2017', category: 'Main Course', freeDelivery: 'No',inCart:0 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Pizza', price: 149, active: 'Yes', dateOfLaunch: '21/08/2017', category: 'Main Course', freeDelivery: 'No',inCart:0 },
    { id: 4, name: 'French Fries', price: 57, active: 'No', dateOfLaunch: '02/07/2017', category: 'Starter', freeDelivery: 'Yes',inCart:0},
    { id: 5, name: 'Chocolate Brownies', price: 32, active: 'Yes', dateOfLaunch: '02/11/2022', category: 'Dessert', freeDelivery: 'Yes',inCart:0}
 ]
 
 for(let i=0; i < carts.length; i++)
 {
     carts[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{ 
         cartNumbers(products[i]);
         totalCost(products[i])
         
     })
 }

 function onloadCartNumbers()
 {
     let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
 
     if(productNumbers)
     {
         document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers;
     }
 }

 function cartNumbers(product)
 {   
     let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
     productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
     
     if(productNumbers)
     {
         localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1); 
         document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers + 1; 
     }
     else
     {
         localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1);
         document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = 1;  
     }
 
     setItems(product);
 }
 
 function setItems(product)
 {   
     let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
     cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
     if(cartItems != null){
 
         if(cartItems[product.name] == undefined){
             cartItems = {
                 ...cartItems,
                 [product.name]:product
             }
        }
         cartItems[product.name].inCart += 1;
     } else{
         product.inCart = 1;
         cartItems = {
             [product.name]: product
         }
     }
     
     localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

function totalCost(product) {
    
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
    
    if(cartCost != null){
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.price);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
    }
    
}
    
function displayCart() {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
   
    if(cartItems && productContainer ){
        productContainer.innerHTML = '';
        productContainer.innerHTML += `
        <table class="product-table">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Free Delivery</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity<th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                </table>
        `
        Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
            productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="product">
                <table class="product-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="product-name">${item.name}</td>
                            <td class="delivery">${item.freeDelivery}</td>
                            <td class="product-price">${item.price}.00</td>
                            <td class="count">${item.inCart}</td>
                            <td class="remove-product"><a href="#" onclick="removeCartItem()">Delete</a>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            `;
        });
        productContainer.innerHTML += `
           <div class="basketTotlContainer">
                <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
                    Total<span>Rs${cartCost}.00</span>
                </h4>
            </div>
                
        `;

    }
   
}


function removeCartItem(product){
    
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    
    for(var i in cartItems) {
       if(cartItems != null){
           localStorage.removeItem('cartNumbers',cartItems[i].inCart--);
           localStorage.removeItem('productsInCart',cartItems[i]);
           localStorage.removeItem('totalCost');
        } else {
            console.log("empty");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "cart is empty";
        }
       
    }
    
}
    
onloadCartNumbers();
displayCart();
```

here using the I have grabbed the data using the class names and added a event listener for click event to add the data to local storage.Now I want to write a function to remove the data from local storage when clicked on delete.
The function `removeCartItem` removes everything from local storage but I want to  remove a particular data only

Comment: How should we know? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211123/need-to-add-and-delete-items-from-a-shopping-cart-using-javascript-jquery) post has adding and removing example. It can help.

Comment: Hello, this looks like a task you received at work. StackOverflow is for such questions, but for other format, e.g. I've created this logic (example) and when I'm trying to call "delete method" it fails with exception "Exception occurred...". Did anyone encountered a similar issue with "delete method" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want actual help you will need to show us some code. 
But there are multiple ways to go about this. Just load the local storage back into a list / array, delete an item from the collection and put it back into local storage. Or have the class automatically update data in the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('dell')
for(var i=0; i< removeCartItemButtons.length; i++){
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
    button.addEventListener('click',function(event){
        let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    
    for(var i in cartItems) {
       if(cartItems != null){
           localStorage.removeItem('cartNumbers',cartItems[i].inCart--);
           localStorage.removeItem('productsInCart',cartItems[i]);
           localStorage.removeItem('totalCost');
        } else {
            console.log("empty");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "cart is empty";
        }
       
    }
        location.reload();
    })
}
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer.